# Output of REST API is not matching with the direct query on the database

Tags: rest, jpa

I have a view in the database on top of which I built a REST api. The output of REST API seems like a cartesian product of the two tables which are part of the view. Anyone has any ideas why it is happening?

Below is the relevant java, sql code and output of JSON and SQL

**Bulkdeals.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "BULKDEALS")
    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Bulkdeals.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Bulkdeals b"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Bulkdeals.findByTradeDate", query = "SELECT b FROM Bulkdeals b WHERE b.tradeDate = :tradeDate"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Bulkdeals.findByDate", query = "SELECT b FROM Bulkdeals b WHERE b.tradeDate BETWEEN :tradeDate1 AND :tradeDate2")
})
```

**BulkdealsFacadeREST.java**

```
//Usage: http://localhost:8080/MA/webresources/db.bulkdeals/date/29-JUL-15
@GET
@Path("/date/{Fordate}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Bulkdeals> findRange(@PathParam("Fordate") Date tradeDate) {
    return (List<Bulkdeals>) em.createNamedQuery("Bulkdeals.findByTradeDate").setParameter("tradeDate", tradeDate).getResultList();
}

  //Usage: http://localhost:8080/MA/webresources/db.bulkdeals/date/29-JUL-15/05-SEP-2016

@GET
@Path("/date/{Fromdate}/{Todate}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Bulkdeals> findRange1( @PathParam("Fromdate") Date tradeDate1, @PathParam("Todate") Date tradeDate2 ) {
    return (List<Bulkdeals>) em.createNamedQuery("Bulkdeals.findByDate").setParameter("tradeDate1", tradeDate1).setParameter("tradeDate2", tradeDate2).getResultList();
 }
```

**VIEW**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "TA_USER"."BULKDEALS"
("TRADE_DATE", "SYMBOL", "NAME", "CLIENT", "BUYSELL", "QUANTITY", "TRADEPRICE") AS
SELECT TRADE_DATE, SYMBOL, NAME,  CLIENT,  BUYSELL,  QUANTITY,  TRADEPRICE
FROM STOCKS_DW.TB_BLOCKDEALS 
union 
SELECT TRADE_DATE, SYMBOL, NAME, CLIENT,  BUYSELL, QUANTITY,TRADEPRICE
FROM STOCKS_DW.TB_BULKDEALS
order by 1 desc;
```

**JSON**

```
 {"bulkdeals":[{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},
 {"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},
 {"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},
 {"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},
 {"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},
 {"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34},{"buysell":"SELL","client":"ASHISH  DHAWAN","name":"Allsec Technologies Limit","quantity":99744,"symbol":"ALLSEC","tradeDate":"2015-07-29T00:00:00+05:30","tradeprice":34}]}
```

**SQL OUTPUT**

```
SELECT TRADE_DATE, SYMBOL, NAME, CLIENT, BUYSELL, QUANTITY, TRADEPRICE FROM BULKDEALS where trade_date = '29-JUL-2015' ;

 29-JUL-15  ALLSEC  Allsec Technologies Limit   ASHISH  DHAWAN  SELL    99744   34
 29-JUL-15  ARCHIDPLY   Archidply Industries Limi   BP FINTRADE PRIVATE LIMITED BUY 129910  53.98
 29-JUL-15  ARCHIDPLY   Archidply Industries Limi   BP FINTRADE PRIVATE LIMITED SELL    124880  54.09
 29-JUL-15  BROOKS  Brooks Lab Limited  GKN SECURITIES  BUY 84900   85.54
 29-JUL-15  BROOKS  Brooks Lab Limited  GKN SECURITIES  SELL    84900   84.13
 29-JUL-15  CEREBRAINT  Cerebra Int Tech Ltd    SHAH NIRAJ RAJNIKANT    BUY 49036   15.14
 29-JUL-15  CEREBRAINT  Cerebra Int Tech Ltd    SHAH NIRAJ RAJNIKANT    SELL    490000  15.23
 29-JUL-15  DOLPHINOFF  Dolphin Offshore Enterpri   CREST CAPITAL & INVESTMENT  BUY 111000  122.01
 29-JUL-15  DOLPHINOFF  Dolphin Offshore Enterpri   PRIYANKA FINANCE PVT LTD    SELL    100000  121
 29-JUL-15  GMBREW  GM Breweries Ltd.   BP FINTRADE PRIVATE LIMITED BUY 153273  302.21
 29-JUL-15  GMBREW  GM Breweries Ltd.   BP FINTRADE PRIVATE LIMITED SELL    147521  303.78
```

Comment: You can try to enable logging of statements that are sent to DB.